# python socket does not connect to other networks

Tags: python, sockets

hi guys i'm studying socket in python, i'm having a hard time connecting with other machines

I have this simple code

```
import socket
host = ''
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((host, 222))
print('wait...')    
sock. listen(1)
conn, addr = sock.accept()
print('connected')
```

the code above is a server, I try to connect using this simple code

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('192.168.0.14', 222))
```

when I execute the client code, nothing happens, it is in an infinite wait, neither the server responds nor the client responds.

obs: this is my goal to connect to an external network on my network. The server code is running on another network, I want to connect to another network

Comment: Help us with your network configuration (firewall, internal and external network), rounting table, subnets

Comment: Is the remote host behind a firewall?

Comment: as I'm new to networking, I think this network may be behind a firewall, list my network settings I don't know how to tell you.

Comment: I do not know how to pass the network and firewall settings, I thought I could make a dual connection with the remote host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code, and it's basically correct. But I don't think your port is perfect, it should be at least 1024.

You should make sure that the port(222) in firewall on your server computer is open.

I changed your port to 12345, it works on my computer.